# Using SED in Makefile to replace filenames generated by yarn with a hash

Tags: sed, makefile, yarnpkg

I am using the `yarn build` command inside a Makefile, which generates two files with names that contain hashes, like `main.abc123.js` and `main.def456.css`.

These files need to be referenced from an HTML file, so I've tried automating the entire process. The relevant part in my Makefile is :

```
build-da:
    yarn build

    $(eval JS_FILE:=$(shell python -c 'import json, os; config=json.load(open("build/asset-manifest.json")); print(os.path.basename(config["main.js"]))'))
    $(eval CSS_FILE:=$(shell python -c 'import json, os; config=json.load(open("build/asset-manifest.json")); print(os.path.basename(config["main.css"]))'))

    $(SED) -i -e 's/main\.[^.]*\.js/$(JS_FILE)/g' my_file.html
    $(SED) -i -e 's/main\.[^.]*\.css/$(CSS_FILE)/g' my_file.html
```

Basically, I'm grabbing the generated filenames from `asset-manifest.json` and trying to use sed to replace that name inside the html file.

This works perfectly fine about 80-90% of cases, but it sometimes fails without any reason, so I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: "_but it sometimes fail without any reason_" ... how do you know?

Comment: It doesn't replace the filenames. "without any reason" = it doesn't give any error or warning.

Comment: The only cause for sed to "fail" that comes to my mind is that the my_file.html is overwritten after sed got to see it. Does the `yarn build` spawn a process which produces this file or is my_file.html a static part of the build?

Comment: `my_file.html` is static. The generated file is `asset-manifest.json` from where I'm grabbing the needed filenames. But I've echoed the vars `JS_FILE` and `CSS_FILE` and those are properly retrieved every time.

Comment: I'm not certain what extra constraints being in a makefile add to this problem, but normally, I would say "you want `$(SED) -i -e "s/main\.[^.]*\.js/$(JS_FILE)/g" my_file.html` . The single quotes hide interpolation of the variable values, so use dbl-quotes". Also, you can do both substitutions in one call to `sed`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I don't think that the interpolation is hidden as it happens inside make which is completely unaware of quotes, be it single or double ones.

Comment: The problem is that make is evaluating all make-functions in a recipe before it executes the recipe, so you end up with wrong or missing contents in your variables if you try to access files which are yet to be built by that very recipe.

Comment: 1) Does it fail consistently, on the same cases? 2) What sed commands do you see echoed to the screen in a failure case?

Comment: I just ran a few more tests and realised that the recipe actually reads a wrong version of `asset-manifest.json`, so I'm guessing that's because the `yarn build` command keeps a write lock on the file and doesn't allow Make to read the most recent contents....

So my question should be more concerned with yarn rather than sed, I'll write a new question or edit it to show off the real problem.